# How to change mysql connect_timeout in opencart?

Tags: php

Thanks everyone, 
I am trying to change the mysql.connect_timeout in opencart admin panel, I have tried many things none of them worked,
first I changed in admin/php.ini and public_html/php.in:

```
mysql.connect_timeout = 28000;
mysql.wait_timeout = 28000;
mysql.interactive_timeout = 28000;
```

it didn't work, next I added these lines to admin/index.php

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 14400);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 14400);
```

and I also changed /etc/my.conf by adding those lines:

```
wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
```

it didn't work.
I am looking in phpinf(), it still shows timeout as 60 no changes,

What can I do?

Comment: did you restart the mysql service?

Comment: yes, I restarted, but it did't work

Comment: make sure you had edit the right file, 'strace mysql' check this out ;)

Comment: it seems that there are two files,

/etc/my.conf.d/server.cnf

/etc/my.conf.d/mysql-clients.cnf

Comment: I guess you should check the /etc/my.conf.d/server.cnf, and also, if you can run phpinfo(), you should check the path for php.ini too. Since the default config file location maybe not the real location somehow.

Answer (score 0):

PHP.ini file contents:

mysql.connect_timeout = 20;

[Ref](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=123003)